What is the reason Spring Security redirecting to /error in this case?
I have a simple SecurityFilterChain configuration and a simple customAuthenticationFilter implementation.
The customAuthenticationFilter (addFilterBefore) just finds the ROLE's from postgresql DB based on the username in the decoded JWT , other than that it is just a regular filterchain.
But when I tried to access any of the endpoint, spring security redirects its to /error path.  I would be very appreciated if anyone point me the reason behind this.
Please also not that this project is deployed to the redhat openshift. Same project works fine locally..
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(customAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        String hierarchy = "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_MODERATOR \n ROLE_MODERATOR > ROLE_USER";
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFilter(userService);
    }

Here is the TRACE log of spring boot where it redirects to /error path for no reason..


 21:12:10.941 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /userlogin
 21:12:10.941 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
 21:12:10.941 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CsrfFilter (6/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@463e0b6a]]]
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (7/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (8/14)
 21:12:10.942 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
 21:12:10.943 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter - Returning no authorities since could not find any claims that might contain scopes
 21:12:10.943 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider - Authenticated token
 21:12:10.944 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@99c731b6, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.88.85, SessionId=96FED99CA7077F197D1F9684BA982785], Granted Authorities=[]]
 21:12:10.944 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CustomAuthenticationFilter (9/14)
 Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.username from user_table u1_0 where upper(u1_0.username)=upper(?)
 21:12:10.945 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.username from user_table u1_0 where upper(u1_0.username)=upper(?)
 Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from user_roles r1_0 join roles r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
 21:12:10.947 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from user_roles r1_0 join roles r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (10/14)
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (11/14)
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (12/14)
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@4a202ba1]
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@4a202ba1] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@20ec6fdd
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Y_SALDAMLI, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST, ROLE_USER]]
 21:12:10.949 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /userlogin
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@597ef918, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1af6cd73, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5a720cdf, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@69eb88a7, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@50cfe725, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3fcc58f8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@472073bb, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@15c27b65, com.thy.rs13guipoc.config.CustomAuthenticationFilter@2baf2c6, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1377af49, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4ac7f844, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2c226db0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@15cba6dc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@25727f74]] (1/1)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CsrfFilter (6/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (7/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (8/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CustomAuthenticationFilter (9/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (10/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (11/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (12/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2d44adc5]]
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2d44adc5]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@20ec6fdd
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 96FED99CA7077F197D1F9684BA982785 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Y_SALDAMLI, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST, ROLE_USER]]
 21:12:10.951 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error

Edited >> More logs
 23:44:22.926 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /api/users
 22:43:48.574 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/api/users", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration'
 22:43:48.575 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
 22:43:48.575 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] TRACE org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor - Skip: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
 22:43:48.576 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
 22:43:48.576 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/users.]
 22:43:48.576 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
 22:43:48.577 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={masked}
 22:43:48.577 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - 2 matching mappings: [{ [/error]}, { [/error], produces [text/html]}]

Spring boot Security redirects to /error path for every endoints except the /actuator.
